# "unused argument" error when calling `select` after applying the `bake` function

Tags: r, tidymodels

I have a question regarding the `bake` function. My dataset consists of 2 variables: the dependent CHURN_FLAG and the independent amount of resources MT_RESOURCES.

When I perform the `bake` function, I get this error:

> "Error in select(., -CHURN_FLAG) : unused argument (-CHURN_FLAG)"

This is the code I use:

```
MT_RESOURCES <- c(10, 20, 34, 5, 20, 9, 10, 60, 5, 1)
CHURN_FLAG <- c("YES","YES","YES","NO","YES","NO","YES","YES","NO","NO")
ddata <- data.frame(MT_RESOURCES, CHURN_FLAG)
glimpse(ddata)
```

Output:

> ```
> Rows: 10
> Columns: 2
> $ MT_RESOURCES <dbl> 10, 20, 34, 49, 20, 44, 10, 60, 44, 1
> $ CHURN_FLAG   <chr> "YES", "NO", "YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES", "NO", "NO"
> ```

Code:

```
rec_obj <- recipe(CHURN_FLAG ~ ., data = ddata) %>%
  step_center(all_predictors(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_scale(all_predictors(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  prep(data = ddata)
```

Output:

> ```
>       role #variables
>    outcome          1
>  predictor          1
> ```

Training data contained 10 data points and no missing data.

Operations:

- Centering for MT_RESOURCES [trained]
- Scaling for MT_RESOURCES [trained]

Code:

```
x_ddata <- bake(rec_obj, newdata = ddata) %>% select(-CHURN_FLAG)
```

Output:

> Error in select(., -CHURN_FLAG) : unused argument (-CHURN_FLAG)

Comment: Maybe you have loaded some other (than dplyr) package whose own **select** method interferes? Check, e.g. the console output for something like "the following methods are masked from 'package:dplyr': ..." see: https://www.statology.org/dplyr-error-in-select-unused-arguments/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is preferable, for the unwary cut and pasters who might also be working on something else in their session, in addition to helping you, to not put `rm(list = ls())`, as they will lose their other work.

Answer (score 3):

You may have another package like MASS masking the Select function. Try specify the package the function comes from.

```
dplyr::select(-CHURN_FLAG)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `new_data` with the underscore.